# tracking points in a shuffle point array

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, computer-vision, scikit-learn

Think about such an array:

```
[(0, -5), (0, -3), (0, -1), (0, 1), ...]
```

In the array above, as we see the point is moving through y angle on x axes.

But at the following array;

```
[(0, 3), (0, 5), (5, -15), (0, 7), (5, -13), (0, 9), (5, -11), (5, -9), (0, 11), ...]
```

as you can see there is a new tracking point is added to the array.

The first point has started from (0, -5) and moving through (0, 9). As you can see, the second point started from (5, -15), and it is also moving through (5, -13), (5, -11)... etc.

Is there a function to differentiate the tracking points, and separate them respectfully?

Thanks,

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: I am going to update the question now.

Comment: If the points move at a constant speed you could check each new tuple if it fits the predicted next position of any points you have so far. If not, it has to be a new point. The problem is to determine the speed of the new point... (because a second measurement of that point could also be a new point) Do you have any additional assumptions/restrictions?